# Hue - setting up path to PIG param_file - how?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

What should I put in pig editor in properties section to use file with my  pig parameters?

there is a hint:

- input /user/data
- -param input=/user/data
- -optimizer_off SplitFilter
- -verbose

But how to use it for param file - not clear.

I tried to set in Pig parameters in :

```
Name field: -param_file Value field: /user/test/pig_parameters.param
```

Getting error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main  - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File /user/test/pig_parameters.param does not exist
```

what is the right syntax ? may be the path should be defined other way? 
Seems hue substitute -param key word during execution.

Comment: where is your pig_parameters.para file , in local or in HDFS ?

If you are running your pig script in Mapreduce mode then parameter file should be in HDFS and respective path

Comment: My param file on HDFS, I'm running pig from hue. When I ran pig in map reduce mode from local : pig -param_file /home/test/pig_parameters.param /home/test/mypigscript.pig - everything works well. I want to ran it from Hue editor